# Script for pasting values where paste-to location vairies by date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet used to track labor costs, where someone enters the number of people in each function hourly. At the end of the day, the sum of hours in each function then gets copied and pasted into another sheet which calculates costs and other metrics. In this sheet, each column represents a day, so the paste range changes each day.

I would like to place a button in the hourly tracking sheet that publishes the hours into the daily sheet. The script required would need to find the paste to range based on the date.

For example, the range being copied is always Hourly!Q6:Q15 and the paste range today is Daily!E6:E15. Tomorrow the paste range would be Daily!F6:F15, The next day would be Daily!G6:G15, and so on.

Only the values should be pasted and formatting should be ignored.

I have figured out how to paste values from one place to another but have hit a wall trying to get the script to paste to a variable location.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
        function PasteHours() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('NV Hourly');
  var daily = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Daily");  
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/DD/yyyy")

  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][1] == date){ 
      Logger.log((i+1))
      return i+1;
    }
  }


  ss.getRange("Q6:Q15").copyValuesToRange(daily, i, i, 6,15)

}
```

Comment: Also I should mention that the header in each column is the date - So today's date can be matched with a column.

Comment: included attempt in original post. Thank you

Comment: So you're trying to copy values to the next free row in your "daily" sheet depending on the date?

Comment: Copying to the next free row is not ideal in case the person using the sheet presses the button multiple times. The piece that I am missing is a function that finds the column number containing today's date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code slightly. Here we use some "reference" date, for which target range is `Daily!A6:A15`. Using it, we can calculate only time difference and progressivly shift the target range in future.

```
function pasteHours() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('NV Hourly');
  var daily = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Daily");  

  // Copy data to column A at this "reference" date
  var sinceDate = Date.parse('2019-07-15');
  var now = new Date();
  // Time difference in days
  var i = (now.getTime() - sinceDate) / 24000 / 3600;
  i = Math.ceil(i); // round up
  Logger.log(i);

  // Will copy to B6:B15 at 2019-07-16 and so on
  ss.getRange("Q6:Q15").copyValuesToRange(daily, i, i, 6,15);
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I see where you are going with it but I'm not sure how to adjust the starting column. Column A and B are both "headers". Dates start at Column C on 6/24/19

Comment: I have realized why my code and this code do not work - it is because I omit weekends from the dates. Dates that land on saturday or sunday are skipped.

Comment: If dates start at col C on 6/24/19 (2019-06-24), then you I can suppose that col A is for two days ago, 6/22/19. So you can correct `var sinceDate = Date.parse('2019-06-22');`. But if you should exclude weekends... This is essential part not mentioned above, sorry. It needs a bit more complicated approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your problem:

**Easy and fast**

If you just want to append a new column to the right of the data range every time you run the script, all you need is to find the last column in "Daily" with `getLastColumn()`:

```
function PasteHours2() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('NV Hourly');
      var daily = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Daily");  
      var i=daily.getLastColumn()+1;
      ss.getRange("Q6:Q15").copyValuesToRange(daily, i, i, 6,15) 
     }
```

**Iterating through dates**

This is probably what you intended. You need to change your code in the following way:

1. If you date in the column header (the first row of every column), modify `if(data[i][1]...` to `if(data[0][i]...`, given that the first index is the row, and the second the column, and the first index of an array is always "0".
2. I assume data is located in the sheet daily, rather than ss: `var data = daily.getDataRange().getValues();`
3. You cannot compare dates directly - you need to convert them to milliseconds for comparison. So select only the date without the time of the dates with `getDate()` and transform it to milliseconds with `valueOf()`: `if(data[0][i].getDate().valueOf() == new Date().getDate().valueOf()){...`
4. Assign the value of `i+1` to a auxilary variable `j`, if the condition is fulfilled.

Here the full code:

```
function PasteHours3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('NV Hourly');
  var daily = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Daily");  
  var data = daily.getDataRange().getValues();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/DD/yyyy")

  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[0][i].getDate().valueOf() == new Date().getDate().valueOf()){ 
      Logger.log(("i+1: "+i+1))
      var j=i+1;
    }
  }
  ss.getRange("Q6:Q15").copyValuesToRange(daily, j, j, 6,15)
}
```

Please find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) more information about working with dates in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. It looks like the getDate function does not work in google script?

Comment: The code above does work for me. What is your issue with it?

Comment: It is producing an error "TypeError: Cannot find function getDate in object"

Comment: maybe this is because your content data[0][i] is not a date/ not formatted as a date?